# Where should I ask a question about using OpenGL shaders in Minecraft?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question about replacing OpenGL shaders with a resource pack for Minecraft [on a non-SE forum](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/java-edition-support/3158802-how-to-replace-a-spectator-shaders-w-shaders-that). That site, The Minecraft Forum, seems to have less activity than it used to. I think it would be much better to ask it on a Stack Exchange site, but the problem is that I have no idea which site I would ask this on.

Does anyone know the best site to ask this on?

Comment: [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) maybe?

Comment: @Smitop You're probably right, but I thought since this stuff might have some programming involved, it might be Game Development. I just wanted to make sure I would ask it on the right site before I would get downvoted like crazy and then get the question closed

Comment: Also consider [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) then: it has a [minecraft-modding] tag with some questions about Minecraft mod development that might be a better fit.

Comment: Yeah, but let me be clear: ***it is completely vanilla***

Comment: It's funny because no one ever answered my question. I asked it on arqade. I ended up finding the answer in a YouTube video with *very picky* Google search terms